# Где нужно прописать delete?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

При перегрузке оператора "+" класса дробь я создаю новый объект в динамической памяти и сразу же возвращаю. Где и как в программе мне нужно удалять его?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define N 10

class Fraction
{

private:
    int chys,
        zn;
public:
    Fraction()
    {
        this->chys = 0;
        this->zn = 0;
    }

    Fraction(int chys, int zn)
    {
        this->chys = chys;
        this->zn = zn;
    }

    Fraction(const Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->chys = obj.chys;
        this->zn = obj.zn;
    }

    int GetChys() { return chys; }
    int GetZn() { return zn; }
    void setFraction(int x, int y) { chys = x; zn = y; }

    int CommonZn(Fraction *B)
    {
        int q = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; q != 1; i++)
        {
            if ((i % this->zn == 0) && (i % B->zn == 0))
            {
                q = 1;
                this->chys *= (i / this->zn);
                B->chys *= (i / B->zn);
            }
        }
        this->zn = i - 1;
        B->zn = i - 1;
        return i - 1;
    }

    int skor(int *chys, int *zn)
    {
        int i = 0, b = 0;
        if (*chys > *zn) { b = *chys; }
        else (b = *zn);
        for (i = b; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (*chys%i == 0 && *zn%i == 0)
            {
                *chys = *chys / i;
                *zn = *zn / i;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

    void comperizon(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        if (A->chys > B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Перший дріб більший за другий" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys == B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Дроби однакові" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys < B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Другий дріб більший за перший" << endl; }
    }

    void addition(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys + B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nСума дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void subtraction(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys - B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nРізниця дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void multiplication(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->chys);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->zn);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nДобуток дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void division(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->zn);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->chys);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nЧастка дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    Fraction const& operator=(Fraction &second)
    {
        chys = second.chys; zn = second.zn;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->CommonZn(&obj);
        return (this->chys == obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator >= (Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->CommonZn(&obj);
        return (this->chys >= obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator > (Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->CommonZn(&obj);
        return ((double)this->chys / this->zn > (double)obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator < (Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->CommonZn(&obj);
        return ((double)this->chys / this->zn < (double)obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator <= (Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->CommonZn(&obj);
        return (this->chys <= obj.chys);
    }

    friend Fraction& operator +(Fraction &first, Fraction &second);
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &in, Fraction &fraction);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr);

    ~Fraction() {}
};

Fraction& operator +(Fraction &first, Fraction &second)
{
    first.CommonZn(&second);
    return *new Fraction(first.chys + second.chys, first.zn);
}

istream &operator >> (istream &in, Fraction &fraction) 
{
    in >> fraction.chys;
    in.ignore(1);
    in >> fraction.zn;
    return in;
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr)
{
    out << fr.chys << "/" << fr.zn;
    return out;
}

void Sort(Fraction *FrArray[]);
//double avarage(Fraction FrArray[]);

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("color f0");
    system("cls");
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int chys1, zn1, chys2, zn2;


    Fraction *PtrFrArray[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        PtrFrArray[i] = new Fraction(1 + rand() % 10, 1 + rand() % 10);
        cout << *PtrFrArray[i] << endl;
    }

    Sort(PtrFrArray); 

    cout << endl << "Сортований масив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << *PtrFrArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    double avar = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        avar += (double) (*PtrFrArray[i]).GetChys() / (*PtrFrArray[i]).GetZn();
    }
    cout << "Середнє значення масиву = "  << avar/N << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete  PtrFrArray[i];
    }


    Fraction *A = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nПерший дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *A;
    Fraction *B = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nДругий дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *B;  
    Fraction *C = new Fraction(*A);

    cout << "Enter C " << endl;
    cin >> *C;
    if (*A > *C && *C < *B) cout << "Успішне порівняння" << endl;
    else cout << "Помилка" << endl;

    cout << "A+B+C = " << *A + *B + *C;


    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete C;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Sort(Fraction *FrArray[])
{
    Fraction changer;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (*FrArray[i] > *FrArray[j])
            {
                changer = *FrArray[i];
                *FrArray[i] = *FrArray[j];
                *FrArray[j] = changer;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*double avarage(Fraction *FrArray[])
{
    double avar = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        avar = avar + (double)(*FrArray[i]).GetChys()/ (*FrArray[i]).GetZn();
    }
    return(avar/N);
}*/
```

Comment: Воспользуйся умными указателями. Там где ты уверен что ты больше не обратишься к этому объекту там и вызывай деструктор. Правда лучше пользуйся std::unique_ptr , отличный пример что бы понять что умные указатели прекрасны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего - никак. Прекратите заниматься такой белибердой, как создание результата оператора в динамической памяти. И константную корректность тоже следовало бы подправить (везде, не только здесь)

```
Fraction operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    first.CommonZn(&second);
    return Fraction(first.chys + second.chys, first.zn);
}
```

И почему `CommonZn` принимает свой операнд как `Fraction *B`, а не `const Fraction &B` - тоже не ясно.

---

Ааа, вижу! Ваш `CommonZn` модифицирует свой правый операнд! То есть даже ваш оператор `+` *модифицирует* свои операнды (!). Оператор сложения, который модифицирует свои операнды (даже если фактическое значение дроби не меняется) - это неприемлемо. Надо переделывать намного больше. Например

```
Fraction operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    Fraction first_common = first, second_common = second;
    first_common.CommonZn(second_common);
    return Fraction(first_common.chys + second_common.chys, first_common.zn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Плохое решение.

Возвращайте не ссылку, а *объект* -

```
Fraction operator +(Fraction &first, Fraction &second)
{
    first.CommonZn(&second);
    return Fraction(first.chys + second.chys, first.zn);
}
```

Так оно гораздо лучше.

И еще - я бы ваши конструкторы заменил на

```
Fraction(int chys = 0, int zn = 1):chys(chys),zn(zn) {}
Fraction(const Fraction &obj):chys(obj.chys),zn(obj.zn) {}
```

ну и еще по мелочам переделал бы... Но это уже другой вопрос...